# Making a image of a infected server to do forensic

Tags: linux, debian

Today I got this email.

> sadly we have to inform you, that your vServer #11260 (IP: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX) >must be closed because of an ominous process.
>
> Our system identified following command, which maybe starts forbidden processes on your server. These processes expulse either against our AGB or against the counting laws. Please fail to do the use of following programms on your server:
> python /tmp/.update/Miner/miner_cli.py -o stratum+tcp://pool2.democats.org:45570 -u KeYmFknkcesVmAXseLBTBybeAhYjfvb1thzwB2pEX5KhErbz3yKbyJv7ioMLWFXDUd4jVFTdtyEsSjBRexKw7vseMDLXPtY.2500 -p x

The support told me they can start the server for a few moments so I can do backups of my stuff. But is there a tool (and how to use it) to make an image of the whole system so I can do some forensics on my local computer?

It is Debian 8 if it matters.

Comment: One Linux native option would be `dd`.

Comment: You may have received a spam email.  Note the misspellings, grammar mistakes, and strange words.  Please improve your question by adjusting the formatting with https://superuser.com/editing-help ; I suggest a block quote for the email.  Please put in the precise email, but obfuscate the names and IP addresses.

Comment: Adjusted the formatting. I am not a native speaker so please excuse my misspellings. Which strange words? Edit: There is no more information in the mail and it is also not a spam mail.

Comment: Can they boot it in some kind of recovery mode? Then you could use ``dd`` or ``partimage`` to create a disk image as backup. Else try using tar with numeric owner parameter. This is the best thing to get a machine cloned on file system layer. Stop all programs you don't need before, so they don't change files during the backup.